# Cancelling google sign in gives error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an app that uses google play games services and one of my beta testers has reported that when you first install the app, and it comes up with the option to **Cancel** or **Sign In**, the app crashes when you click **Cancel**.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I am using the BaseGameUtils library to handle the entire sign in procedure.

Also, I wanted to recreate this so I can check the logs but for some reason, when I uninstall my app and install it again, it doesn't show the **Cancel** **Sign In** dialog, it just logs me in so I can't see what the logs are saying.

Comment: Look at what @VenomVendor said below, then can we see how you handle the login and/or how you handle any shared preferences?

Comment: Change your Google account password and try.

Comment: @VenomVendor It worked, unfortunately, my one is not crashing... How am I supposed to debug this.

Comment: @Ogen No idea, but when I get a crash in my app, I add some junk message and submit the crash report. Later view than in my developer console to get the logs. Alternatively I use BugSense to get immediate crash reports.

Comment: To make it easier, just call `mHelper.signOut()` in your app. Then during the next start or sign-in attempt it will prompt you to choose an account again (no need to uninstall/change password). As for the problem, make sure that you implemented the `onActivityResult` properly - and that it does not attempt to access something that might be null.

Comment: @free3dom I don't know what is called when that sign in thing comes out. The sign-in thing that says cancel and sign in, so I don't have a callback for when they press cancel.

Comment: @Ogen AFAIK the account chooser/sign-in is done in a separate activity which is part of Play Services. This is why I am thinking that the crash (most likely) happens in `onActivityResult`, because it will get called regardless of whether you sign-in or cancel.